# Apache Webserver on Linux config - Can I create a Virtual Index.html

Tags: linux, apache-2.2

I have number of directories under Apache webserver on linux. 
I need a file - index.html in each directory. Can I keep a master index.html file in a specific location and tell apache to use this just incase there is no real index.html file in one of the sub directories ?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this (You need to enable Mod_rewrite)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/user_dir/index.html !-f
RewriteRule (.*) /master_dir/index.html [L]
```